# Setting up vault with kubernetes auth throws x.509 error

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/vault-agent-k8s

When I try to:

```
curl --request POST \
        --data '{"jwt": "'"$KUBE_TOKEN"'", "role": "example"}' \
        $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/kubernetes/login | jq
```

I get:

```
https://my.endpoint.ip/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine doesn't trust the Certificate Authority which is used to setup the Vault. You can either setup your machine to trust the Certificate Authority or ignore certificate validation if you are just testing the setup. To ignore validation in curl you can use `-k` flag as follows:

```
curl -k --request POST \
        --data '{"jwt": "'"$KUBE_TOKEN"'", "role": "example"}' \
        $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/kubernetes/login | jq
```

If you are using a vault client to make the request, you can set `VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY` environment variable:

```
$ export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=1
```